# How to detect correct email address with machine learning using textblob?

Tags: python, machine-learning, textblob

I want to detect the correct email address but my code is giving me the tag with major probability in the dataset and obviously it don't work like i expected.

Here is the code:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
files = [
  ("data_train/email_positive.txt", "yes"), 
  ("data_train/email_negative.txt", "no")
]
train = []; cl = None

for file_txt in files:   
    email_train_raw = []        
    with open(file_txt[0]) as f: 
        email_train_raw = f.readlines()

    for email in email_train_raw:
        e = email.replace("\n", "")
        train.append( (e, file_txt[1]) )

cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
print cl.classify("wrong_email@2x.png")
# Output: yes 
# it would be: "no"
```

Some correct email dataset:

```
hello@3commerceinc.com
sales@ablefreight.com
dispatchwaycross@absolutewl.com
ops@absolutewl.com
tol@absolutewl.com
email@gmail.com
email@hotmail.com
. . .
```

Some incorrect email dataset:

```
pause@2x.png
video@2x.png
right@2x.png
play@2x.png
circle-hover@2x.png
preloader@2x.gif
left@2x.png
circle@2x.png
. . .
```

Comment: As i understand the tutorial [textblob#classifiers](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#classifiers), this will only work with **sentence**.

Comment: well, thank you sir. If it is not possible. I will close this thread